# Can I export my form so I can use it outside of Cognito?

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to connect my DB to the form and have it prefill fields based on login from my DB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can export your entry data on the Entries page to Excel, but we do not offer the ability to export a form.

You can have data prefilled onto a form by passing values into the form through the url, you can learn more about this process in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/65/data-integration/prefilling-a-form).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Cognito Forms](https://cognitoforms.com). You can export your entry data on the Entries page to Excel, but we don't offer the ability to export a form in Cognito.